# Get list of file for a user excluding sharewithme?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

We have a Apps Script that change the owner of some documentation in a shared folder on a generic account. Employee put their documentation into the folder and the script flip the owner to the generic account and give Editor access to the previos owner. In that way if employee leave the company, the ownership stay to that generic account.

BUT

recently user started to share documents and folders with that generic account instead of moving it directly into the generic account drive/folder.

So at the end, we don't want all the files and folder that are "SharedWithMe" to have owner changed. We only want those that are contained directly under the generic account drive.

I'm looking to find a query that I can be use as params with the  `DriveApp.searchFolders()` and `DriveApp.searchFiles()` method so that only "local" files/folder are processed by my script

For now I have this to get only file that the generic account is not already the owner..

```
var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('not "username@domain.com" in owners');
```

I need to add to that a kind of exclusion of all files/folder that are only `sharewithme`

For now I try

- `var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('not "username@domain.com" in owners and sharedWithMe=false');`
- `var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('not "username@domain.com" in owners and sharedWithMe!=true');`
- `var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('not "username@domain.com" in owners and not sharedWithMe=true');`
  ...etc..etc..

I also test only the query using the `File.list` API Explorer and the only thing that return some results is `q = sharedWithMe=true`  or `q = sharedWithMe`

These bug tracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36759777) workaround doesn't apply as we are looking only for file that the account is not already the owner....the goal of our script is to change the owner to the generic acount..

So how to exclude in the list of files/folder returned all those sharewithme...?